# Store and retrieve millions of JSON-encoded events (PHP/Database)

Tags: php, mysql, json, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

Let's assume we have the following example JSON event data:

```
{
    "eventId":"eb1363c3-6bf7-4a42-9daa-66270b922367",
    "timestamp":"2014-10-28T09:12:22.628Z",
    "ip":"1.2.3.4",
    "device":{
        "type":"mobile",
        "os":{
            "name":"iOS",
            "version":"7.1.1"
        },
        "name":"iPhone 4/4s",
        ...
    },
    "eventType":"AddedProductToCart",
    "store":"US",
    "product":{
        "sku":"ABC123",
        "name":"Yellow Socks",      
        "quantity":1,       
        "properties":{
            "foo":"bar",
            "bar":1
        }       
        ...
    },
    "user":{
        "id":123456,
        "name":"jeff",
        "type":"registered"
        ...
    }
}
```

while "eventId" and "timestamp" will always be supplied, the structure of the array can vary and is not the same. There are around 30-40 unique eventTypes, all with different event properties. Most of the event data have a nested structure.

What would be the best approach for storing those event properties? I have looked into MongoDB, DynamoDB and a project called EventStore (http://geteventstore.com). Obviously I have also considered MySQL, but I am wondering how it would perform in our use case.

The storage of the data is only the first part. After this, we should be able to query our database / event storage with complex queries like the following (and not only retrieve by indexed ID for example):

```
select all events where eventType is "AddedProductToCart" and timestamp > 2 weeks ago
-> should return all "AddedProductToCart" from 2 weeks ago until now

select all events where device.OS.name is "iOS" and device.OS.version is "7.1.1"
-> should return all events from iOS 7.1.1
```

etc.

We are expecting around 10 million events per month. This amounts to 3-4 writes per second on average, and probably more like 30-40 writes per second peak / worst case scenario. Storage should not really be an issue - total size per event will likely not exceed 1 or 2kb (this amounts to 1-2GB per 1 million events).

The querying part should be in PHP, preferably. DynamoDB for example has an SDK for PHP, which will certainly facilitate our

What would be our best solution for this? Writes should be blazing fast and our querying should also be acceptable. In a nutshell, we're looking for a low-cost data store to easily store and then retrieve (->queried not only using an index but also by using event properties from the nested JSON) our data.

Thanks for any suggestions, and if more information is required to properly answer this question, I'd be glad to supply more information.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon's DynamoDB offers a fully managed (auto-scaling), durable, and predictable solution.

Judging by the amount of traffic and data you expect, DynamoDB’s free tier of 25 write/read capacity units and 25 GB covers your operations basically for free.

Each write capacity unit is equivalent of writing 1KB of data, so if you’re expecting 3-4 writes per second of 2KB data, you need to provision 8 WCU’s.  In addition, DynamoDB's performance extremely is predictable with fast single digit millisecond latency.  For more information about the free tier, check out http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/.

In terms of your data set, for non-document objects querying is relatively simple with the use of global secondary indexes.

**Here’s an example from the PHP SDK.**

```
$twoWeeksAgo = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-14 days"));
$response = $dynamoDB->query(array(
   "TableName" => <Table Name>,
   "KeyConditions => array(
      "EventType" => array(
           "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
           "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array(Type::STRING => "AddedProductToCart")
            )
      ),
      "Timestamp" => array(
           "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator:GE,
           "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array(Type::STRING => $twoWeeksAgo)
               )
          )
     )
 ));
```

You can query "Device.OS.Name" and "Device.OS.Version" via a scan, but there are a couple of optimizations you should consider based on what kind of queries you want to make.

If you're looking to make adhoc queries,  you can make a parallel scan call and then apply the ScanFilter using a ConditionalExpression on your nested attributes.  By parallelizing your scan, you optimize the consumption of read capacity units on your table as well as the speed of the operation.  For more information about parallel scan, check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScanParallelScan.

Alternatively, if you have select attributes you want to query, consider making some of the fields top level attributes or move them into their own separate table, flatten the necessary attributes (i.e. os.name to osname) and have a back reference to your original item (mainly applies to your documents like "device").  By doing this, you can add indexes on top of these attributes and query them quickly and efficiently.  Additionally with the pre announcement of online indexing, you should be able to add and remove indexes where necessary to meet your requirements soon.

If you would like to discuss this in further detail or ask questions in general about using DynamoDB, feel free to reach out to me by private message.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Raymond, thank you for your detailed answer. As I said in a comment to the above answer, I have experimented with PHP and DynamoDB. I've had some issues however storing nested JSON (map or list) within dynamodb using the PHP SDK. For more information, please see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593112/aws-php-sdk-issue-dynamodb - If I can sort out those issues, I'll gladly give DynamoDB another try - seems like the logical solution as our whole operation is practically entirely AWS based

Comment: Hey, in your example code, I noticed that your map has a string literal as its value.  In DynamoDb, each value in a document should be an attribute value, while keys are always just strings.  I have posted the fix in the other thread.  Let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a good bet here. It can handle the write/s easily (the `mongod` sees more action on my laptop).

The queries you mentioned are basic ones. For example:

```
db.collection.find({"device.OS.name":"iOS","device.OS.version":"7.1.1"})
```

and (shortened for readability)

```
db.collection.find({"eventType":"AddedProductToCart",timestamp:{$gte: ISODate(iso8601String)}})
```

With indices set correctly, those should be lightning fast. You can even use TTL indices to automatically remove events older that a certain time.

For data analysis, you have both map/reduce and MongoDB's extremely powerful aggregation framework.

Let's come to the downsides. While scaling is relatively easy with MongoDB, for some reason people assume that a replicated sharded cluster with automatic distribution of data is as easy to manage as the rest of MongoDB. The keyword is that it is *relatively* easy (compare it to replicated data partitioning with MySQL or - Lord help us - Oracle), but still it has some pitfalls.

Point-in-time recoveries in a sharded environment without the use of MMS are possible, but you really have to know what you are doing since the synching of the individual backups of the shards is quite tricky.

No matter which database you choose, I strongly advice to get into touch with an according specialist. Production data is elementary and no database with it should be planned and maintained by non-specialists.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Markus. I will look into MongoDB. I have just set up an experiment on DynamoDB - it seems that what I am trying to do is only achievable by using "Scan" (see more here: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)). I quote "A Scan operation examines every item in the table." - this seems very slow, and from what I've read it gets also expensive. How does MongoDB compare? By the way, I am a student and we're doing this project as an experiment / for fun. we're no experts by any means as you can see by my cluelessness ;-)

Comment: (I will keep this question open for a bit longer to allow more suggestions. I will select a correct answer when I've looked into every single suggestion)

Comment: With clever indexing, you will achieve better results with MongoDB as with Dynamo and a scan. You might be able to tweak Dynamo too, however. As always, the question is _what_ you want to do, not _how_ you want to do it.