# DynamoDB Scan with multiple, nested JSON keys (PHP)

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My data is stored in a single table "events" in DynamoDB in the following schema with "_id" as hash key and "microtime" as range key (example data below):

```
{
  "_id": {
    "S": "ae3761b5-b73b-4fb9-ae5a-5cc230b8fa11"
  },
  "data": {
    "M": {
      "name": {
        "S": "Jeff"
      },
      "purchase_value": {
        "N": "25"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "N": "1201"
      }
    }
  },
  "microtime": {
    "N": "14147568808639"
  }
}
```

I am using AWS PHP SDK 2.7.0 to scan the database based on my filters (in this example, primary hash key "_id"). My code below that works perfectly (**returns correct entry**):

```
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
                'key'    => 'key',
                'secret' => 'secret',
                'region' => 'eu-west-1'
));

$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan', array(
    'TableName' => 'events',
    'ScanFilter' => array(
        '_id' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array('S' => "ae3761b5-b73b-4fb9-ae5a-5cc230b8fa11")
            ),
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
        ),
    )
));

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
  print_r($item);
}
```

now when I try to scan based on data INSIDE of the "data" element, **I can't get any matching entries**. Example code below (I am trying to extract all with data.name=Jeff):

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan', array(
    'TableName' => 'events',
    'ScanFilter' => array(
        'data.name' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array('S' => "Jeff")
            ),
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
        ),
    )
));

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
  print_r($item);
}
```

Anyone can see any issues with my code, or is it in fact not possible to extract data by comparing values INSIDE of a JSON document? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

I've tried the following code from DynamoDB PHP SDK Documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/Aws/DynamoDb/dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#scan) - **still no success**. I can only retrieve when scanning using primary hash/range key, and any other ("first-level") key, but not using a key from INSIDE of a document (map/list) like in my example. See below:

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan', array(
    'TableName' => 'events',
    'ScanFilter' => array(
        'data' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array(
                    'M' => array(
                        'name' => array("S"=>"Jeff"),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to my issue:

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan', array(
    'TableName' => 'event_test2',
    'FilterExpression' => 'event.customer_name = :filter',
    "ExpressionAttributeValues" => array(":filter"=>array("S"=>"Jeff")),
));
```

More information here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164470

Comment: You could use marshaler to save headaches on data types: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.Marshaler.html

Answer (score 1):

From the API, it seems possible, but I've never actually tried it. That is definitely *not* the correct syntax though. Look at the [`Scan` API docs for the upcoming Version 3 of the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/Aws/DynamoDb/dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#scan) (Version 2 docs do not include the newest DynamoDB features, due to some technical limitations). You will need to use nested `AttributeValueList` parameters. You may also want to ask about this on the [official DynamoDB forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131).

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion (see above edit) using sdk version 2.7.0 and 2.7.2. I am not sure if I still got some syntax issues with my edited code, but I do not get any errors from the sdk (similar behavior to when the scan has no matches, but in my case there should be several matches). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I have just posted this question on the official DynamoDB forum, as you suggested. For reference, I am also including a link here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164470 - Should I get any updates there, I'll report back here on stackoverflow with more info.

Comment: Darn, well, I'll try to see if I can get some more info on this Monday. If you end up posting on the DynamoDB forum, make sure to add a link to the post here.